# shell script-Unable to get expected response by running through loop inside .sh file, but getting it by individually defining variables in file

Tags: json, api, shell, curl, jq

**Fileread.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
s=ch.qos.logback
e=logback-access
curl -s "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:$s+AND+a:$e&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json" | jq ".response.docs[].v"`
```

output:"1.2.11"

This code is working perfectly fine  But when I try storing the s and e values in a .txt file with  : seperated and then try running, I get nothing in response

**textFile.txt**

ch.qos.logback:logback-access

**fileread.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter file name:" filename
while IFS=':' read -r s e
do
curl -s "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:${s}+AND+a:${e}&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json" | jq ".response.docs[].v"
done < $filename
```

I have tried :

```
xy=$(curl -s "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:${s}+AND+a:${e}&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json" | jq ".response.docs[].v")
echo "$xy"
```

```
xy=$(curl -s "'https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:'${s}'+AND+a:'${e}&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json" | jq ".response.docs[].v")
echo "$xy"
```

```
url=`https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:${s}+AND+a:${e}&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json`
echo url

xx=`curl -s "$url" | jq ".response.docs[].v"`
echo $xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter file name:"
read filename

IFS=':' read -r s e < $filename
echo $s $e

curl -s "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:${s}+AND+a:${e}&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json" | jq ".response.docs[].v"
```

~